# Index Out Of Bounds Exception Java Index: 3, Size: 3

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, while-loop, stringbuilder

Hi guys while making a word-puzzle game, I came across a problem in double checking that the vertical and horizontal were both words from my current file that was saved to an arraylist.

```
 String letterSize = "" + size;
    makeLetterWordList(letterSize);
    boolean finished = false;
    while ( !finished ) {
        finished = true;
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            int randomYWord = randomInteger(wordList.size());
            String item = wordList.get(randomYWord);
            puzzleListY.add(item);
        }
        for (int i = 0; i <= puzzleListY.size(); i++) {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            for (int j = 0; j <= puzzleListY.size(); j++) {
                sb.append(puzzleListY.get(j).charAt(j));
            }
            randomXWord = sb.toString();
            if (!wordList.contains(randomXWord)) {
                finished = false;
                break;
            } else {
                puzzleListX.add(randomXWord);
            }

        }
    }
```

The error Produced was as follows:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 3, Size: 3
at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(ArrayList.java:653)
```

I am struggling to find the mistake in my code can anyone assist me?

Comment: What was the first line in the error that mentioned your class?

Comment: An array of size 3 has indices 0, 1, 2.. find out why your code is trying to access the non-existent index 3. It's a coding error; which is an individual developer task .. using a debugger (or a pencil and piece of paper) can be helpful tracing a program.

Answer (score 2):

Loop should be only till size - 1

```
for (int i = 0; i <= puzzleListY.size(); i++) { // remove =
```

For other loop as well, Since you are starting from index 0 and there are n elements loop should be from 0 to n-1

Comment: Same thing with the inner loop (using `j`).

Comment: @TedHopp I am still receiving a error, however it produces the error if run but on occasion it runs correctly. New error java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 3

Comment: Must be in this line: `sb.append(puzzleListY.get(j).charAt(j));`? charAt(j) is causing some problem, how are you sure that there is a character at index j?

Comment: @JacksonPayne - Did you change both loops to stop _before_ `puzzleListY.size()`?

Comment: @TedHopp that is correct I have fixed the error simply needed to clear the ArrayLists at the start of the while loop

Comment: If this is the answer, could you please mark it as such.